# doctrine 2.15; entity relational mapping with broken database

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have to work with a broken database that I can't fix (I only have readonly accesses).
There are 2 tables: `contact` and `contact_type`

When I try to fetch contacts I have an error "Entity of type ContactType for IDs id(0) was not found."

Indeed in the table `contact_type`, the id 0 does not exist.

Is there a way to define a default value to null when the relation is not found?

```php
#[ORM\Entity]
Contact
{
  #[ORM\ManyToOne]
  #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: true)]
  public ?ContactType $contactType = null;
}
```

I tried to use the JoinColumn columnDefinition and options but it does not seem to do anything.
I would like to only use attributes to fix this problem since I am using a framework that manages all the filters on its own without needing to have a custom repository.